# InCorrect Map In AutoMapper When Map Model To ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, automapper

I Have an Model"TClientsAdmins" and ViewModel is TClientsAdminsViewModel.I want read all records from DB where filtered by id.
I Read they from domain model and when I want Map to viewmodel I get zero Count in viewmodel.
In addition I have a model that is called THoldingAdmins That is associated with TClientsAdmins.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }


   public int? THoldingAdminsId { get; set; }


   public virtual THoldingAdmins THoldingAdmins { get; set; }
```

and TClientAdminViewModel :

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }


    public int? THoldingAdminsId { get; set; }


    public virtual THoldingAdminsViewModel THoldingAdmins { get; set; }
```

and THoldingAdmins:

```
    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }


    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }


    public virtual List< TClientsAdmins> TClientsAdmins { get; set; }
```

and AutoMapper Configuration :

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<TClientsAdminsViewModel, TClientsAdmins>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<List<TClientsAdminsViewModel>,List<TClientsAdmins>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an explicit mapping for `IList`, but it does look like you have your mapping the wrong way round, if you're mapping from Model to ViewModel.  Try

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TClientAdmins, TClientAdminsViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<THoldingAdmins, THoldingAdminsViewModel>();
```